# Laravel 4: Variable in routes

Tags: php

I tried to pass variable in route with this, and it works:

```
Route::get('/path', array("as"=>"myname", function(){
    $data = include app_path()."/views/myconfig.php";
    return View::make('pageview',$data);
}));
```

As I need to use the data in most routes, I am thinking to move the `$data` outside so that it looks cleaner.

```
$data = include app_path()."/views/myconfig.php";

Route::get('/path', array("as"=>"myname", function(){
    return View::make('pageview',$data);
}));

Route::get('/path2', array("as"=>"myname2", function(){
    return View::make('pageview2',$data);
}));
```

But this end up giving me error saying that `Undefined variable: data`. Why is it moving it up become unreadable? What do you suggest a better way I can do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to Laravel, it is the matter of PHP itself

```
$data = include app_path()."/views/myconfig.php";

Route::get('/path', array("as"=>"myname", function() use ($data){
    return View::make('pageview',$data);
}));

Route::get('/path2', array("as"=>"myname2", function() use ($data){
    return View::make('pageview2',$data);
}));
```

Why it does not work in your code? Because of scopes. `$data` is defined out of callback function's (or closure, call it whatever you want) scope - it's not available for callback. `use` keyword let's you do this.